# Angular 2/4 Routing: Does it perform like a native mobile app or do I need to resolve states?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, performance, architecture

I just want to keep things simple - how is Angular 2/4 resolving previous components data state in my application without any routing resolves implemented? I am using the recommended Angular setup (CLI ^4.2.4)

Here is the scenario

1) Navigate to a route view that fires up view specific components that do some API requests for data and show items
2) Click on an item and go to a different view using different components that also do API requests for data
3) Click back on the browser and the previous view is displayed (Although through stress testing and using different IDE's it is not always consistent..which worries me)

Is the previous state of the components saved in the browsers cache/heap or does the Angular framework perform some kind of magic to accomplish this?
I am aware that in a native mobile app, previous views are just layers that never actually "go away". When a new view is selected, the old one is still there in the background. Or do I have that wrong?

On my last project I used a view resolver to get data for the previous view. It took time to implement, but it worked flawless. I am curious to see if using resolves for future projects is a sound decision or just overkill and actually losing performance features of new Angular

Comment: Angular does not save the previous state. If you go back to a previous route, it trigger the routing and re-render the view like the first time. If you perform API call, it will do it again, each time you want to render this component. But you can store the API data in some cache, and get your data from this cache when you want to render your view. Take a look at redux or ngrx to manage this kind of state.

Comment: Hmm, I agree that redux/flux state machine design patterns are a good solution (React is awesome for that :-) I am just trying to stay in the recommended bounds of Angular routing as per their documentation for now. Anything automagical just scares me and I wanted to float this question by the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data and storing state are 2 different concerns.

Angular does not automagically perform either but provides you with built-in tools to accomplish both.

**To load data from an API, you can:**

- load the data in a [router resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard) if you need the data before the route components are instantiated
- load the data in a component if you wish to immediately show the component while the data is still being loaded (you will have to make sure your component can handle an "empty" state while there is no data available yet)

**If you wish to store the resolved data in your application, you can:**

- store the data in a service
- store the data in a data store like [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform)
- store the data in a browser storage mechanism like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Which of the above you use to accomplish your goals depends greatly on your application's needs and your personal preferences.

You may even opt for a resolver to load data in one part of your application while loading data inside a component in another part of your application.

Comment: Thanks @jvandemo! I think the simple fact that data is loaded in the component answers the question (I have used services, storage and resolver's in the past) Another important caveat I'm learning here (Thanks again @Noémi Salaün) is the importance of using ngrx in a complex app right from the beginning is also (especially where concurrency is a concern) I'm wondering if things will change with newer versions of Angular lol